# Have I forfeit some of my comment flags?

Tags: discussion

I've had the [maximum of 100](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) available comment flags for some time. It's been my observation that the number of available flags is decreased by one for each outstanding flag; however as flags are handled the available flag count goes back up.

A bit ago I flagged a comment and noticed my available comment flag count is not 100:

[image]

The only flag I have pending is the one I just cast:

[image]

I'm pretty sure the available flag count hasn't gone down because of declined flags, since the last comment flag I had declined was on Jan 27 2018. I don't have any other type of flags outstanding either, in case that matters.

What could be the reason I'm "missing" 12 comment flags?  Did I do something to make this happen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> however as flags are handled the available flag goes back up.

That is not entirely wrong, but also not correct. Handled flags do not directly go back to your daily allowance. Sometimes, it may look this way when a handled flag increases your limit, since the limit  goes up by one with each ten helpful flags. This happens one in ten times, and only until you hit the maximum daily limit of 100 flags.

So, the likely reason you have fewer than 100 flags available is that you raised some today. ("Today" refers to UTC time)

Comment: I'm not certain how the increase in max flags is relevant (it's been a while since I reached the 100 flag max). However, it seems you're saying you don't get your available flags back until 0:00 UTC? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You got it. I obviously never realized the available flag count wasn't reset until 0:00 UTC. Further I confirmed at the time of posting my question I had indeed raised the exact number of "missing" flags since 0:00 UTC.

Comment: Its pretty hard to use all your flags on the same day too.